# Append stdout to file, but continue to output to console

Tags: linux, bash, stdout

On linux/bash I'd like to append stdout of a command to a file, but not redirect it (i.e. I want it to to go to both console and file). Any clues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think "tee" is the right command for this -- unfortunately I don't know the exact syntax. Tee writes its input to stdout and to a file.

Comment: I looked it up and the basic syntax is: command | tee file.txt

Comment: And a merry christmas to you too!

Comment: If you want to append to the file (instead of overwriting), use `command | tee -a file.txt`